# nHibernate result from multiple SQL queries is empty

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, multi-query

I'm grouping several SQL queries in a single multiquery. The queries are successfully executed. The result of `multiQuery.List()` is an `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists`. So far so good. However, the individual `ArrayLists` contain values of type `{object[0]}` or, if I use a result transformer, properties with their value set to `null`. I won't list the entire set of SQL queries here but this is what my multi query looks like:

```
        var multiQuery = Session.CreateMultiQuery()
            .Add<IList<DTO1>>("query1", query1)
            .Add<IList<DTO2>>("query2", query2)
            .Add(..)
            .Add(..);
        var results = multiQuery.List();
```

Pretty standard in my eyes, but it doesn't work unfortunately. I'm using the latest version of Fluent nHibernate (1.2). This version comes with nHibernate 3.1 by default, which doesn't support SQL queries inside a multi query.

To get this working, I added nHibernate 3.2 to my project and added the following to my web.config.

```
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate"
                              publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.1.0.4000"
                             newVersion="3.2.0.4000"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: does it return correct data if executed one at a time?

Comment: yes, when I just do `query1.List<DTO1>();` the results are returned just fine.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of it?